# Wix Tools from Command Window

Tags: wix, wix3.6

Is it possible to use wix commands from the command window?  I have the wix 3.6 toolset installed and although the Wix Project is available, it seems that the project template does almost nothing to help you create a project.  From my understanding, all the helpful tools are command based and are not accessible from the command window (at least they aren't for me).  Am I missing something?  It would seem rather unhelpful to have a visual studio project where you have to type all the xml by hand and then leave the IDE to use any of the useful tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call executables from the command window. For example, to call Heat with the /? param:

```
Tools.Shell /o /c heat.exe "/?"
```

Note that I have the WiX Toolset bin directory set in my Path.

You can also [create code snippets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx) to speed up entering repetitive xml.

Comment: After I posted that I see I didn't address the initial question. I'll update my answer in a moment.

Comment: Best answer I have seen so far.  Although it seems odd that the Wix Addon itself wouldn't make this easier somehow. I would expect that if one were to make an add-on for Visual Studio, it would be helpful to have the commands that are unavailable through wizards/menus/forms to be accessible through the command window without having to jump through any hoops.  It may be that I am unaware of how difficult this may be to achieve (I have never written a VS addon) so I will reserve judgement until I have written an addon of my own ;-)  Thanks BryanJ.

Comment: @BitFiddler The issue is that WiX has been the side project of some Microsoft developers. While I believe it is the best tool to create installation packages for Windows platforms, they could do a lot more with WiX if it was given more attention.